# Links in the old review panel contain HTML entities

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, review

The disable random link at the end of the pages in the old review queue doesn't work - since the `&` are HTML escaped into `&amp;`

```
http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&amp;pagesize=15&amp;filter=day&amp;no-random=1
```

There is the same escaped HTML problem for the enable random ordering, get X more post links, mobile link (at the end of the page, near contact us), custom filter (currently hidden - probably a new feature). @Andrew Barber found out that the custom sort options on the right panel also have the same problem. I have confirmed via Firebug that the rest of the links don't have this problem.

The no-random page is still there and can be accessed if I modify the link.

Comment: Incidentally, once you get random disabled (by modifying the URL), the sort type links that are on the right side are similarly broken.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Nice find - I never know that it's there. I actually used jQuery and dump all links in the console and slowly scroll through the page and find the options for sorting >_<

Comment: possible duplicate of [Questions list pager link has overescaped ampersand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146162/questions-list-pager-link-has-overescaped-ampersand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 0):

Since the bug has persisted for 3 days, and without any response from the dev team, I wipe up this UserScript for Greasemonkey as a temporary measure to reduce the annoyance of typing the URL by hand.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Fix &amp; bug on SO review
// @namespace   org.nhahtdh.stackoverflow.reviewlink
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/review/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href*="&amp;"]').each(function () {
        this.href = this.href.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
    });
});
```