# Disabling random ordering in review doesn't work

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable random in old review queue doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144724/disable-random-in-old-review-queue-doesnt-work)

I'm not sure if there was a change in the system, but currently I cannot disable random ordering on the review pages ("First Answers" and "Late Answers").

When I click `disable` random ordering, the page gets loaded again, but paging isn't activated and I get 30 random posts displayed.