# Mobile search page controls fail due to double-encoding

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, mobile-web, encoding

The page controls (switching between pages, changing page size, etc)  on the mobile site search results don't work correctly, due to what looks like double-encoding of the query string.

For instance, attempting to navigate to page two of [this search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+footer) (`[feature-request] footer`) on mobile brings you to

```
/search?page=2&amp;tab=Relevance&amp;pagesize=15&amp;q=%5bfeature-request%5d+footer
```

which just shows the search help page due to the double-encoded `&`. It seems that the page size switcher on the non-mobile view also has this problem:

```
/search?tab=relevance&amp;pagesize=30&amp;q=%5bfeature-request%5d%20footer
```

Similarly, the page size selector form gets passed the URI-encoded value of the search query, which gets encoded again as part of the form submission. Changing the page size of the above search results on mobile produces

```
/search?q=%255bfeature-request%255d%2Bfooter&pagesize=15
```

where the `%` in the already-encoded `[` and `]` have been encoded again to `%25`, breaking the search input.

Comment: related bug in [su] meta - [Possible bug in "Low Quality Posts"](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5511)

Comment: I reported somewhat similar bug nearly 2 weeks ago, no response: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144724/disable-random-in-old-review-queue-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: My fault for including three slightly different issues in the same report, but the second issue (double-encoded `&` on full site page size switcher) and the third issue (double-URI-encoded `q` value on mobile page size switcher) are still present. Should I split them out into their own posts?

Comment: @Tim no, I'll look into them.