# Mobile user profile activity paging over-escapes page querystring parameter

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, mobile-web, recent-activity

On my Android device the "activity" paging from my profile page appears broken. The page links are rendering the `&page=n` as `&amp;page=n`.

When I manually change the link to the non-entity version I get the appropriate page.

(I recall someone else seeing a rendering issue, although IIRC that wasn't mobile.)

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you ran into the broken paging? I reported that the [search paging was broken on mobile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145948/mobile-search-page-controls-fail-due-to-double-encoding) earlier, but that's since been fixed (just confirmed).

Comment: Ah, I see it's at least still broken in the profile page, and the sort order parameter on the `/questions` route still gets a double-encoded `&` too.

Comment: @TimStone Sorry, yes, worst bug report ever.

Answer (score 3):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: Thanks all :) and more words.