# "Get 30 more" while reviewing first questions resets filters

Tags: discussion, bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links in the old review panel contain HTML entities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144724/links-in-the-old-review-panel-contain-html-entities)

I've found this today, and don't know if it's a bug, or if it is intended.

So, I'm reviewing First Questions atm. Since the language I know best is C++, I decided to review some C++ - related questions. I pressed the `C++` tag on the right, and pressed the "All" button to see all of the questions. Until this point it works fine, and shows me random 30 questions from all time, which are C++ tagged.

However, when I've checked them all, and I press the "30 more" link in the bottom to get more questions, my tag selection and my time selection both get cleared, and I'm redirected to a page which shows me random 30 question with *any* tags, from *today only*.

The URL for all-time C++ questions is

```
http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=all&tag=c%2b%2b
```

but after pressing "30 more" I'm redirected to a page with the following URL:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&amp;pagesize=15&amp;filter=all&amp;tag=c%2b%2b
```

which differs in the `amp;` added after each parameter.